# When form submission not accepted, dependent selector is messed up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with a selector/drop-down menu that's dependent on another selector. In other words

-there is selector 1, which contains some number of categories, and selector 2, which contains some number of subcategories for each category in selector 1.

-when the page loads, selector 1 has its full range of categories available, and selector 2 has its full range of subcategories available.

-when a selection is made on selector 1, the number of available subcategories on selector 2 is narrowed down (as appropriate for the option selected on selector 1) through $('selector1').change(function(){ [... functionality implemented ...] });

The problem is that when a user submits the form, and the form is not accepted (i.e. contains errors in the fields, fields are not filled-in, etc.), since the 'change' functionality is not re-triggered, the full number of subcategories becomes available on selector 2, which makes it possible for a user, through mischief or accident, to select a subcategory which does not apply to the category selected on selector 1. Any recommendations on how to best deal with this issue? Thank you!

Comment: "So listen, my car's making this clunky sound, maybe the Engine? Transmission. Anyway, I don't know. Do you know what the problem is?" ... *pause from mechanic* .... "You'll have to bring the car in so we can look at it"... **Where is the code!!**

Comment: As stated in the post, it's pretty probable that the problem has to do with the fact that the javascript 'change' function isn't re-triggered when a form is not accepted. Pseudo-code is in the third bullet point in the post. The form itself is auto-generated through web2py's sqlform functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing how your code looks, I can only take a guess. It sounds like you need to have a function that will load the 2nd list's items based on the currently selected item in list 1. If you already have that function, just call it on page load and whenever the form is 'not accepted' Make sense?

Comment: Sure, but I suppose I was wondering if there was some ready solution that would retain the form's previous state on the reload.

Comment: Alright, went with this option. Thanks.